# Invalid write and read, in merge sort C

Tags: c, sorting, valgrind

Valgrind complains about my code at some points and I really have no Idea why.. I basically took an finished code for merge sort (descending order) and adapted it, because I want later not to have the sorted list, but just the order its elements are now, so If I have:

5   8   1   2
[0] [1] [2] [3], 
after sorting it is:

8   5   2   1

[1] [0] [3] [2]  <== This is what I want

So my code is split in three parts:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int *llist, *array_ordered;
int end,fst, i ; //will be set somehow
array_ordered = malloc(sizeof(int)*(end-fst));
llist = malloc(sizeof(int)*(end-fst)); //filled with some numbers
for(i =0; i < (end-fst); i++) array_ordered[i] = i;

 sort_list(end-fst, llist, array_ordered);
```

}

```
void sort_list(int total, int *llist, int *array_ordered) {

  int i, j, temp, *temp_array; 
  temp_array = malloc(sizeof(int)*total);

  for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  temp_array[i] = llist[i]; // copying the values, because I need my original list to keep
  }
  merge_sort(temp_array, total, array_ordered);
 free(temp_array);
```

}

```
void merge_sort(int *A, int total_el, int *array_ordered) {
  int i;
  int *list_one, *list_two;
  int *order_one, *order_two;
  int num1, num2;

  if (total_el < 2) return;   /* the array is sorted when n=1.*/

  /* divide A into two parths the list, and the positions (array_ordered)*/
  num1 = total_el / 2;   /* the number of elements in A1 */
  num2 = total_el - num1;  /* the number of elements in A2 */
  list_one = malloc(sizeof(int)*num1);
  list_two = malloc(sizeof(int)*num2);
  order_one = malloc(sizeof(int)*num1);
  order_two = malloc(sizeof(int)*num2);

  /* move the first n/2 elements to A1 */
  for (i =0; i < num1; i++) {
    list_one[i] = A[i];
    order_one[i] = array_ordered[i];   <=== invalid read of size 4
  }
 for (i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
    list_two[i] = A[i+num1];
   order_two[i] = array_ordered[i+num1];  <=== invalid read of size 4
 }

 merge_sort(list_one, num1, order_one);
 merge_sort(list_two, num2, order_two);

 merge(list_one, num1, list_two, num2, A, array_ordered, order_one, order_two);
 free(list_one);
 free(list_two);
 free(order_one);
 free(order_two);
```

}

```
 void merge (int *A, int a, int *B, int b, int *C, int *array_ordered, int *order_one, int  *order_two) {
  int i,j,k;
  i = j = k = 0; 

  while (i < a && j < b) {
    if (A[i] >= B[j]) {
    /* copy A[i] to C[k] and move the pointer i and k forward */
      C[k] = A[i];
      array_ordered[k] = order_one[i];    <=== Invalid write of size 4!
      i++;
      k++;
    }
    else {
      /* copy B[j] to C[k] and move the pointer j and k forward */
      C[k] = B[j];
      array_ordered[k] = order_two[j];
      j++;
      k++;
    }
  }
  /* move the remaining elements in A into C */
  while (i < a) {
    C[k]= A[i];
    array_ordered[k] = order_one[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }
 /* move the remaining elements in B into C */
  while (j < b)  {
    C[k]= B[j];
    array_ordered[k] = order_two[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }
}
```

And I have no clue, since all of the lists have the same total num, why would I write at one point only in the list of positions illegally :S

```
==1373== Invalid read of size 4
==1373==    at 0x10001F1D5: merge_sort (main.c:5586)
==1373==    by 0x10001D2E0: sort_list (main.c:5512)
==1373==    by 0x10000A164: my_function (main.c:1014)
==1373==    by 0x1000032E5: main (main.c:450)
==1373==  Address 0x244fd9a70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,512 free'd
==1373==    at 0x4D9D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:479)
==1373==    by 0x10000A1A4: my_function (main.c:1020)
==1373==    by 0x1000032E5: main (main.c:450)

and 
==1373== Invalid write of size 4
==1373==    at 0x10001F3BC: merge (main.c:5529)
==1373==    by 0x10001F2C0: merge_sort (main.c:5602)
==1373==    by 0x10001D2E0: sort_list (main.c:5512)
==1373==    by 0x10000A164: my_function (main.c:1014)
==1373==    by 0x1000032E5: main (main.c:450)
==1373==  Address 0x244fd9a70 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,512 free'd
==1373==    at 0x4D9D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:479)
==1373==    by 0x10000A1A4: my_function (main.c:1020)
==1373==    by 0x1000032E5: main (main.c:450)
```

Comment: All invalid accesses involve `array_ordered`, which is passed to `merge_sort`. It has the same dimension as `A`. It would be interesting to know how that array is allocated and how the tom-most call to `merge_sort` looks like.

Comment: As a side note, if you have over 5000 lines long `main.c`, which contains utility functions like sorting, you're asking for debugging headaches. You should separate these to their own modules (such as simply, `merge_sort.c` and `.h`), which you can then test independently (also for corner cases). And it's not waste of time either, you'll spend way more time debugging that `main.c` monster, than you would spend writing a set of test cases for much shorter `merge_sort`-module.

Comment: the array_ordered is allocated in sort_list(), i just called it array_of_pos, sorry for confusing.
And yes you are right, I have to split my method but until now I was dealing with these kind of problems

Comment: Please show the code of the allocation, how you initialise the order array and how you call `merge_sort`. Does the valgrind error occur on arrays of any size?

Comment: Well in my example it is already allocated :S!?  But indeed i did it differently in my original code, so It is like tshi:

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int array_ordered*;
    array_ordered = malloc(sizeof(int)* (end - fst));
}

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter to early;  
SO I fill the indexes end, and fat somehow, just start and end positions, then I call merge sort like this:
sort_list(fst-end, array_ordered, list);
   
And sort list calls merge sort like written in the first post. So the difference in the upper post is that I allocated array_ordered in the sort_list(), here I am giving it as a parameter, but anything else stays the same

Comment: Sorry for confusing to much, I changed my first post now accordingly and wrote how I allocate it

Comment: The new code looks okay. I can reproduce your Valgrind errors if the list of ordered indices is too short. But that's not the case here, at least not in the code you posted. (Which might well not be the _real_ code, given all that editing.)

Comment: Hmm okay, so i cannot correct this error?

Comment: amongst other problems, the size of the array is NOT end-fst but rather end-fst+1.  I,E, a 10 entry array (using offsets) would be 9-0 = 9 which is 1 too small.  (using position counts would be 10-1 = 9, still 1 too small.  Also, I suggest calculating the array size into a variable and always use that variable rather than re-calculating the same value over and over.  one way to get an array size is: sizeof(arrayName) / sizeof(array entry type)